# Line integral on cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: line-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOM7P.png)

Hello, i am having problem with line integral in cylindrical coordinates and especially with this question. I can do the radial lines, but the line integral of 2 straight lines are just coming out wrong and it doesn't match with the Stoke's theorem either. Are there any mistakes with my work?

[My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q263a.jpg)

Comment: Could you please show your work?

Comment: Done! You can look at editted post.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately i couldn't. I am going to try again with a different take on the problem. I will edit the post if i succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that along line $\vec l$ we have for $t\in[2,5]$

- $\vec l(t)=(7-t) \vec a_{\rho}+\frac{\pi}3\vec a_{\phi}\implies \frac{d\vec l}{dt}=-\vec a_{\rho}$

Comment: So what exactly happened to the radius that we are suppose to multiplicate with 'angle' unit vector?

Comment: @GöktuğSaray Sorry I don't get your point